# obtener los datos de calidad de un fastaq

Tags: python

tengo un archivo fastq y necesito extraer los valores de calidad y transformarlos a los números correspondiente SIN usar biopython o ninguna otra paqueteria. Hasta el momento he logrado obtener los valores y ahora estoy tratando de crear una función (quality) que haga la traduccion a numeros utilizando ord(). Allí algo estoy haciendo mal.

archivo_ejemplo:

1. @FCC0U42ACXX:2:1101:17553:4175#ACTACAAG/1
2. AGACA
3. ++
4. bbbee
5. @FCC0U42ACXX:2:1101:17741:4180#ACTACAAG/1
6. CCCAA
7. ++
8. hhhg[
9. @FCC0U42ACXX:2:1101:17512:4183#ACTACAAG/1
10. ATAAT
11. ++
12. cccCB

```
from sys import argv

def record_finder(lines):   
    res=[] 
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if lines[i].strip() == "++":
            res.append(lines[i + 1].strip())
    return(res)

def quality(q_numbers):
    qn=[]
    for i in range(len(q_numbers)):
        qn=ord("res")
    return(qn)
                         
def main():
    
    with open(argv[1]) as fastq:
        fastq_1= fastq.readlines()
        for rec in record_finder(fastq_1):
            qualitys=quality(rec)
    return(qualitys)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: en la parte de quality necesito que tome los resultados de la primer funcion (res) y con ord() los transforme a numeros. ord espera caracteres y res es una lista